# Extra fee doesn't show at the admin panel orders

Tags: magento-1.9

I added an extra fee. It's working well at the checkout. [image]

But at the admin panel -> sales -> orders -> my order it doesn't show. 
[image]

But price is well. 
At the invoice too

[image]

How can I show it? 
I tried :

```
<fieldsets>
     <sales_convert_quote_address>
         <insurance><to_order>*</to_order></insurance>
         <insurance><to_order>*</to_order></insurance>
         <insurance><to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item></insurance>
     </sales_convert_quote_address>
</fieldsets>
```

But it doesn't help. Thanks advance.

EDIT:

```
class Cart_InsuranceUpsell_Model_Paymentinsurance extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'Insurance Upsell';

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getInsuranceUpsellApply()) {
        parent::collect($address);

        $this->_setAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $quote = $address->getQuote();

            $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
            $fee = $address->getGrandTotal() * (Mage::getStoreConfig('cart_insurance_upsells/configuration/discount_rate',Mage::app()->getStore())/100);
            $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
            $address->setInsurance($balance);
            $quote->setInsurance($balance);
            $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getInsurance());
        }
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
            $amt = $address->getInsurance();
            if ($amt > 0){
                $address->addTotal(array(
                    'code' => $this->getCode(),
                    'title' => 'Insurance Upsell',
                    'value' => $amt
                ));
                return $this;
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Config.xml :

```
  <config>
       <global>

        <pdf>
            <totals>
                <insurance>
                    <title>Upsell Insurance</title>
                    <model>cart_insurance_upsell/pdf_earning</model>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                </insurance>
            </totals>
        </pdf>

        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <insurance><to_order>*</to_order></insurance>
                <insurance><to_order>*</to_order></insurance>
                <insurance><to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item></insurance>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
        </fieldsets>

        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <insurance>
                        <class>cart_insurance_upsell/paymentinsurance</class>
                    </insurance>
                </totals>
            </quote>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <insurance>
                        <class>cart_insurance_upsell/earning</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </insurance>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
        </sales>
 </global>
    </config>
```

And for the invoice:

```
class  Cart_InsuranceUpsell_Model_Earning extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice) {
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        $insurance = $order->getInsurance();

        $invoice->setInsurance($insurance);

        $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $insurance);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And can u explain pls, how to work in config.xml that:

```
   <order_invoice>
                     <totals>
                         <insurance>
```

Comment: Did you add any extension for extra fee?

Comment: @SukumarGorai what do you mean by the extensions?

Comment: How did you add extra fee in checkout?

Comment: @SukumarGorai edited question

Comment: Looks ok in first sight. Let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Modify your `config.xml` code like this.

```
<global>
    <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <insurance>
                        <class>cart_insurance_upsell/paymentinsurance</class>
                    </insurance>
                </totals>
            </quote>
            <order>
                <totals>
                    <insurance>
                        <class>cart_insurance_upsell/order_total_paymentinsurance</class>
                    </insurance>
                </totals>
            </order>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <insurance>
                        <class>cart_insurance_upsell/earning</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </insurance>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
        </sales>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <insurance>
                    <file>insurance.xml</file>
                </insurance>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
```

**Step 2 :** create `insurance.xml` with below code at this location.

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\insurance.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <block name="paymentinsurance" type="cart_insurance_upsell/adminhtml_sales_order_totals" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

**Step 3 :** Create `totals.php` at this location with below code.

```
app\code\local\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Totals.php

<?php
class Vendor_Extension_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals 
{

    public function initTotals() 
    {
        if ($this->getSource()->getInsurance()!= 0)
        {
            $parent = $this->getParentBlock();

            $insurancefee = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'  => 'insurance',
            'field' => 'insurance',
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getInsurance(),
            'label' => 'Insurance'
           ));

           $parent->addTotalBefore($insurancefee, 'grand_total');   
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step 4 :** create `Paymentinsurance.php` with below code at this location.

```
app\code\local\Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Total\Paymentinsurance.php

<?php
class Vendor_Extension_Model_Order_Total_Paymentinsurance extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract {

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Order $order) 
    {
       $insurancefee = $order->getOrder()->getInsurance();
       $order->setInsurance($insurancefee);

    $order->setGrandTotal($order->getGrandTotal() + $insurancefee);
    $order->setBaseGrandTotal($order->getBaseGrandTotal() + $insurancefee);
    return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty. But what is  `<class>cart_insurance_upsell/order_total_paymentinsurance</class>`?

Comment: I updated answer, kindly check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Same error i am getting when i am using https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee any help thanks